# Receiving error message when creating user using EM Express

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, oracle-enterprise-manager

Need help, when using Oracle EM Express to add user I'm receiving error messages listed below. I don't have any table space listed and I am logged in as SYSTEM or SYS.

```
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
ORA-06512: at "SYS.PRVTEMX_ADMIN", line 8565
ORA-06512: at "SYS.WRI$_REPT_SECURITY", line 288
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_REPORT", line 898
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

Comment: Is AWR enabled in your DB Installation?

Comment: I am not sure, is there are way to check and if is not enabled to enable?